# Как изменить CSS для конкретного элемента

Tags: css

Есть много элементов с классом `main-gridContainer-gridContainer`, которые нужно уменьшить.

Тогда я в CSS прописываю

```
.main-gridContainer-gridContainer {
    --minimumColumnWidth: 240px !important;
}
```

И всё идеально, все такие элементы на всех страницах стали нужного размера.

Но а если мне нужно что бы у одного из таких элементов было не ***240px***, допустим, ***150px***.

Как его обозначить в CSS? Я его нашел, и это

```
document.querySelector('.test-testOverview-overview 
                        .contentSpacing 
                        .test-testtOverview-testShelfSpacer 
                        .main-gridContainer-gridContainer')
```

Как его записать в CSS?

Comment: так и записать......... и раз везде `!important` то и тут придётся его впихивать

Comment: ТО что ты нашел, это JS...

Comment: Задай этому элементу другой класс и запиши в css так `.main-gridContainer-gridContainer .другой-класс{}`

Comment: @Air, Да разобрался уже, только изменились все `.main-gridContainer-gridContainer` на  странице с классом `.test-testOverview-overview`  , а нужно только первый.  Попробовал, с псевдоклассом `.test-testOverview-overview .contentSpacing .test-testtOverview-testShelfSpacer .main-gridContainer-gridContainer:first-child  {--minimumColumnWidth: 150px !important;}` ,но что то не получается.

Comment: напиши просто `.main-gridContainer-gridContainer:first-child  {--minimumColumnWidth: 150px !important;}`  после строки где написано про `250px`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это изменит на всех страницах первый элемент с таким классом. А мне нужно только первый только на странице `.test-testOverview-overview`

Comment: ну тогда `.test-testOverview-overview .main-gridContainer-gridContainer:first-child` ........ вообще не работать не может, если только не неверно определён селектор и/или переопределение стоит выше основного стиля

Comment: Прочитай про селекторы `CSS`....  Быстрее будет... Чтобы норамльно ответить на твой вопрос, надо видеть верстку.... И ответы и комментарии в данном вопросе, могут тебе помочь...  Прочитай, вникни в суть....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а если, допустим, он не первый, а третий, то как его в CSS записать?

Comment: @FiftyFour7250 `:nth-child(3)` или `:nth-child(2)` - не помню с чего индекс начинается   https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: индекс начинается с 1 (  еденицы  )...

Comment: В общем, то ли вы мне не правильно советовали, то ли у меня "особенная" ситуация, но приписывать child'ов нужно было не к .main-gridContainer-gridContainer, а к  .test-testtOverview-testShelfSpacer

Answer (score 0):

**Конкретному элементу**, которому вы хотите изменить размер, **в html коде напишите айдишник**.
Вот так: id="test".

Типа как тут: `<div id="test">Lorem ipsum</div>`. Классы и все остальное можете оставить, главное написать айдишник

Потом, в стилях, напишите

```
#test {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что нужно было просто приписать `:nth-child(?)`. В итоге, у меня в CSS это выглядит теперь вот так:

```
                    .test-testtOverview-testShelfSpacer:nth-child(2)  .main-gridContainer-gridContainer {
                     --minimumColumnWidth: 150px !important;
                     }
```